# Could not load file or assembly 'Stimulsoft.Report.WebFx, Version=2013.3.1

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

I'm new to developing stimulsoft report in C#/ASP.NET, I got this website file from a friend, but when I run it on my PC, it says the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check if ther is a Stimulsoft.Report.WebFx assembly.
Its version should be 2013.3.1800.

If you use different version of Stimulsoft assemblies, change the version to that you use.